# Changing case (upper/lower) on adding data through Django admin site

Tags: python, django, admin, case

I'm configuring the admin site of my new project, and I have a little doubt on how should I do for, on hitting 'Save' when adding data through the admin site, everything is converted to upper case...

Edit: Ok I know the .upper property, and I I did a view, I would know how to do it, but I'm wondering if there is any property available for the field configuration on the admin site :P

Comment: Both answers where interesting, but I was wanting just doing it when on admin section, thanks both!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your goal is to only have things converted to upper case when saving in the admin section, you'll want to [create a form with custom validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) to make the case change:

```
class MyArticleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
    def clean_name(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["name"].upper()
```

If your goal is to always have the value in uppercase, then you should [override save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) in the model field:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.name = self.name.upper()
        super(Blog, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Comment: for the case of not required fields: `self.name = self.name and self.name.upper()`

Comment: Great example, Small and easily understandable. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Updated example from documentation suggests using args, kwargs to pass through as:

> Django will, from time to time, extend the capabilities of built-in
>   model methods, adding new arguments. If you use *args, **kwargs in
>   your method definitions, you are guaranteed that your code will
>   automatically support those arguments when they are added.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save( *args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to [override save()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).  An example from the documentation:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(force_insert, force_update) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```