# Unique and custom order_id generated by Django Autofield

Tags: django, model

I am building an e-commerce solution that stores unique and custom order_id's for every single order. The uniqueness is due to the separation of orders for 1 particular customer. The custom part is for the separation of different suppliers. For example:

*Supplier name = **foo***

```
order1:  order_id = foo-20202907-001
order2:  order_id = foo-20202907-002
...
```

*Supplier name = **bar***

```
order1:  order_id = bar-20202907-001
order2:  order_id = bar-20202907-002
...
```

The first part of the order_is is depending on the name of the supplier. Next it will take in a date stamp and lastly it takes auto incremented field for the order amount that day.

My current Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The Autofield starts at 1 and increments it every time a new is placed by 1. When a lot of customers are placing different orders at different suppliers the order_id's get really messy. For the sake of the unique id in my payment system i need something like the above order_id's.

I've read some articles about on custom unique field but I don't know whats the right approach. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the save method of your model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.Charfield(max_length=50,unique=True)
    ...

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        order_id = "{}-{}-{}".format(supplier,date_stamp,self.pk)
        self.order_id = order_id
        super(Order,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

For supplier and date_stamp am sure you know how to get the values.
More information about this can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Django does have this covered, according to the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column

So I think it's just up to you how you handle your primary key. You can look up more about custom save methods if you want custom formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8864743).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you both! Based on your answers I've made the following function which concatenates the desired fields an outputs a brand new order_id which also checks for uniqueness. I only still need to change the first field 'ivm' for the supplier name but this will do the trick :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.SlugField(primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True)
    ......

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while not self.order_id:
            new_order_id = '-'.join([
                'ivm',
                now.strftime("%Y%m%d"),
                str(randrange(0, 201, 1)),
            ])

            if not Order.objects.filter(pk=new_order_id).exists():
                self.order_id = new_order_id

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've used a Slugfield instead of the Autofield an used randrange to generate a number from 1 - 200. Is anyone familiar with a function which auto increments and which I can use instead of randrange? If there's none this will do the trick! :)